# New installed PC does not load OS. Motherboard or CPU?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer, intel-graphics

My new installed PC does not load OS

This is first time I tried to build a new PC (I didn't install separate GPU), followings are my steps:

1. Installed New intel i5-10400 10th gen onto New MSI Z590-A pro Wifi motherboard. According the online doc: i5-10400 has integrated graphic card.
2. Installed 16 GB RAM onto motherboard
3. On my personal macbook, Using balenaEtcher to flash Linux Lite image to USB
4. Insert USB, Turn on my new PC.

It could load the BIOS interface. However, after I set to start from USB, then it loads start menu and I select to start Linux System, the screen turns to black and it says "can not find signal"

Comment: Are you using a display port or HDMI connection?

Comment: If you could not load the BIOS, how did you choose to boot into Linux?

Comment: I use HDMI connection @MatthewSchell

Comment: I could load the BIOS. But after BIOS, It shows a list `start from Linux OS, or Linux OS recovery, or System Setup`. I selected to start from Linux OS, then it goes to black screen. @Sam

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? Try with latest Ubuntu or Pop_OS. They have pretty good driver support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linux Mint. I used it several times in different machines and it worked really reliable.

Create your Linux mint boot stick following this guide. https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-create-a-linux-mint-bootable-usb-in-macos/

Then plug in the stick in your PC like you already have done it. When booting Linux mint, you could use the arrow keys of your keyboard to switch between boot logo and logging output. So press your arrow key once to see the logs and watch until it (maybe) fails. Then you could read the error message.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This does not really answer the poster's question, it is more of a suggestion to try a different approach. Please do not post this as an answer but as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl-alt-f3 to get into a terminal where you can maybe do startx and activate the Gui, and if your stuck in a terminal then just double click ctrl-alt-f1. Hope this helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The screen shows "can not find singal", then it turns black.

Comment: Maybe bash is broken or something, you most likely want to just clean install by now or use recovery mode.

Comment: Tried latest ubuntu and it works

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.